# How to display a div to center of the page and auto fit content to page using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to create a modal window which will be displayed in desktop browsers, mobile browser and tablets.

I want to make the absolute position of div at the same time, div should be in center of page in horizontal and vertical.

I tried the following

```
#outerdiv{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0px;
}
#innerdiv{
    width:50%;
    height:100%
}
```

The above code auto fit the content to page. But how to make absolute position or center align in horizontal and vertical. I was displaying this div like a pop up.

Answer (score 3):

To center align a div horizontally, the best trick I believe is:

```
left:50%;
margin-left:-"half the width"px;
```

For vertical alignment I would go with JavaScript and calculate the height of the screen

```
var height = $(window).height();
var div_height = $('#div').height();
$('#div').css('top', (height - div_height) / 2);
```

You could of course also apply this to a parent element by changing "window" to the parent.

Comment: will it takes whole window or current window height?

Comment: The browser viewport's height In my experience it works better than a css solution when it comes to vertical fixing divs...especially smaller devices.

Answer (score 3):

This solution should scale gracefully with window size, and on resize too. We give the parent the width and height of the window like so:

```
body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Then we specify the containing div to:

1. Have half the height and width
2. Pad the top and bottom by a quarter (a half of the space taken up)

Like so:

```
#innerdiv{
    position:fixed;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    top:25%;
    margin-left:25%;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
```

jsFiddle here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97NJG/)

Comment: will settings top 25% will be effective in mobile devices?

Comment: Should be! It's standard CSS, but if not, you could try `margin-top:25%;`. With `top` you are actually moving the position of the div, with `margin-top`, we are setting a margin for the div.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following html structure:

```
<body>
    <div id="yourDiv">
    <!-- modal content -->
    </div>
</body>
```

You can center your container with the following styles:

```
#yourDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Note: you'll need to give your container a height and width for the centering to work.

Here's a [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/j4xBm/1/)

Comment: if window size decrease what will happen? will it make any change in display?

Comment: The modal will remain centered.  You may have to change the size of it, but you can do that using media queries.  This solution will work across all browsers and screen sizes.

Comment: Okay i will try those

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a fixed size of the `.popup`.

```
.popup {
     height: 300px;
     width: 300px;
     position: fixed;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     margin: -150px;
   }
```